# Xcode 10.1 signing problems for the iOS Qt kit

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qml, signing

It's more than a whole day I'm struggling with this problem and whatever I've found on the Web is either related to lower versions of Xcode or not working for these two issue!

Using Qt Creator (Qt 5.12.1), on my macOS Sierra 10.13.6 installed as a virtual machine on VMware Workstation 14 Player on my physical machine Windows 10 x64, I created a simple QML project called *test_2* and configured *Desktop* and *iOS* kits for that.

There is almost no warning in the [*Projects* menu](https://pasteboard.co/I5ha9Ml.png) of the program but the green triangle button for running is greyed out and when I build the project I get this error: 
*:-1: error: Xcodebuild failed.*

The Xcode I've installed on macOS X is version 10.1 and I've signed my Apple ID on the [Accounts menu](https://pasteboard.co/I5hcsjp.png) of that.

Now Xcode shows two errors and I think if these two are solved I can run my QML project using the iOS kit.

How to solve these two issues please?

[image: The errors are related to signing]

Comment: @paulw11: Did you find a proper answer there? I didn't! So how should I use that thread to solve my issues?

Comment: You can use that question to follow the issue.  I don't believe there is a real fix until Apple fixes whatever they broke

Comment: So what can I do? Can't I build my QML projects using the iOS kit? And how long should I wait? Who knows they ever fixes this, since it's a free account. :(

Comment: The issue only started occurring yesterday, so it will probably be fixed soon, but yes, it does only seem to be affecting free developer memberships. There are some suggested work around in the answers to the duplicate. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: None of them worked for me. The only one that could be the solution was on the *~⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨MobileDevice⁩ ▸ ⁨Provisioning Profiles* path while in my macOS X Sierra 10.13.6 there isn't such a path! :(

Comment: I guess the only guaranteed fix at the moment is to pay for a developer program membership.

Comment: OK, thanks. One last question, where should I check to see whether or not the issue is fixed? And if fixed, see the solution.

Comment: All I can suggest is keeping an eye on the duplicate, however you might find that your compilation just starts working.

Comment: There is also [a thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114612) on the Apple developer forums

Comment: I changed my Apple ID and used it to sign in both Xcode and developer.apple. And now there is no signing error in the Xcode menu but I still can't build/run my project in Qt Creator. When I build it, I get the error: "Xcodebuild failed", and in the Run Settings, in the Projects menu it's been written: *To use this device you need to enable developer mode on it*. But on my iPhone it's on developer mode I think. :( How to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Connecting the device via USB to Xcode should enable it for developer mode. Try restarting the device and Xcode/macOS

Comment: I restarted both the device and macOS. Now I can build the project for the iOS kit, but in the project's directory I see no *.api* file! Should I have one with this type for that project there? The second question is although I restarted the machine and device I still get the message "*To use this device you need to enable developer mode on it.*" for Run mode. Is there any reason for that, please?